# Dependency Injector - Wiring sub-libraries

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I don't know if it is available or not at the moment, but I would like to know if exists a particular feature.
I developed a library that uses the dependency injection and this library uses another library that also implements the dependency injection.
For the sake of explanation I'll call the first one libraryA and the second libraryB

Currently I'm working on a project that import libraryA . I wire it like shown by the documentation:
`container.wire(packages=[libraryA])`

Obviously this solution doesn't work because the libraryB isn't directly wired, so the short term solution was:

```py
container.wire(packages=[libraryB])
container.wire(packages=[libraryA])
```

**in this order because otherwise it doesn't work.**

In the future this libraries may be support even more projects, so my question is:
Is there ia better solution to wire the packages some library depends on?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post a [short self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating your issue.  It is not possible to satisfactorily answer your question as it stands because it is incredibly broad.

Comment: I'll edit my question as soon as possible, thank you for the suggestion